# Relate feature with spatial with FSTP

Tags: charts

In S57 file, I want to find out the spatial of a buoy. I have the feature recoprd of the buoy. I want to find out its position, lat & long. Thank you.

I tried everything, but cannot understand the NAME, ie concatetion of RCID and RCNM